# Convert a chain of "condition ? expr1 : expr2" to a chain of "if"s

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

Is there any automatic tool to convert a chain of `condition ? expr1 : expr2` to a more readable chain of "if"s?

**I'm using Java in Netbeans.**

For example:

```
super(dao == null || (dao.isX.get() != null && dao.isX.getBoolean()) ? (isY ? "String1" : (isZ ? "String2" : (isA ? String3 : "String4"))) : "String5", BoxLayout.y());
```

Note: I can do that by hand, but I'm asking for an automatic tool to avoid errors when I find complex chains of `condition ? expr1 : expr2`

Comment: Maybe instead of converting to series of `if`s consider splitting each condition and values to separate line and applying indentation? Something like (first line)  `condition` (second line) `? value`  (third line) `: other value`. Is that acceptable option for you?

Comment: I've just tried indentation as you suggest in the example I provided: it helps a lot and Netbeans suggest automatically the right indentation during the splitting to separate lines. The "Format" option of Netbeans is compatible with your hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super(whatever);` should always be the first line, your ternary operator is a design solution you can't refactor into a chain of `if`s (unless you wrap it into a method as Andy [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57338753/4922375)).

Most modern IDEs can transform a ternary operator into an if statement, no matter how complex an expression might be.

I checked my IDEA on a three-level ternary operation, it suggested

[image]

If yours doesn't have a similar feature, look for a plugin, or consider switching to a more advanced environment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Netbeans 10 doesn't have this option or a plugin to do that. I'm not aware about the last version of Netbeans. If somebody have more info about this issue on Netbeans, please comment... :)

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani I am surprised this pretty basic refactoring isn't provided. Are you looking for it on the `super(....)` code you show in the question? If you are, can you try extracting that expression to a method, and then checking to see if the refactoring is available in that method.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried, without success. The available refactorings provided by Netbeans are shown here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring

Answer (score 0):

`super(...)` (or `this(...)`) always needs to be the first statement in a constructor, so you can't use a chain of if statements there.

It looks like you need to extract a method:

```
static String method() {
  // Chain of if statements.
}
```

Then invoke that from the constructor:

```
super(method(), BoxLayout.y());
```